# What is the correct way to implement NearestNeighbor for TextureAtlas sprites in a Bevy project?

Tags: rust, nearest-neighbor, bevy, texture-atlas

I am trying to set up a bevy project and use pixelart.  
Right now, it uses a textureatlas to load sprites from a single image.

All is working, but I cannot find out how to use NearestNeighbor in my sprites. My sprites are blurry at the moment.
All relevant documentation seems to be pre-bevy: 0.10 as well and seems to be outdated. I also can't seem to find any information about the relevant migrations.
  
Can anyone help me with a way to implement NearestNeighbor in my project?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is how I've currently tried it:

```
use bevy::asset::Handle;
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy::render::render_resource::{AddressMode, FilterMode, SamplerDescriptor};

pub const BACKGROUND_COL: Color = Color::rgb(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);

fn main() {
    App::new()
        //.add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
            primary_window: Option::from(Window {
                title: "Hi".to_string(),

                ..default()
            }),
            ..default()
        }))
        .insert_resource(ClearColor(BACKGROUND_COL))
        .add_startup_system(spawn_camera)
        .add_startup_system(load_spritemap)
        .add_startup_system(spawn_player.in_base_set(StartupSet::PostStartup))
        .add_system(bevy::window::close_on_esc)
        .run();
}

#[derive(Resource)]
struct Spritemap(Handle<TextureAtlas>);

fn spritemap_fix(
    mut ev_asset: EventReader<AssetEvent<TextureAtlas>>,
    mut assets: ResMut<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
) {
    for ev in ev_asset.iter() {
        match ev {
            AssetEvent::Created { handle } => {
                if let Some(texture) = assets.get_mut(&handle) {
                    texture.sampler = SamplerDescriptor {
                        address_mode_u: AddressMode::ClampToEdge,
                        address_mode_v: AddressMode::ClampToEdge,
                        mag_filter: FilterMode::Nearest,
                        min_filter: FilterMode::Nearest,
                        ..Default::default()
                    };
                }
            }
            AssetEvent::Modified { .. } => {}
            AssetEvent::Removed { .. } => {}
        }
    }
}

fn load_spritemap(
    mut commands: Commands,
    assets: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut texture_atlases: ResMut<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
) {
    let image = assets.load("Spritemap.png");

    let atlas = TextureAtlas::from_grid(
        image,
        Vec2::splat(8.0),
        16,
        11,
        Some(Vec2::splat(2.0)),
        Some(Vec2::splat(1.0)),
    );

    let atlas_handle = texture_atlases.add(atlas);
    commands.insert_resource(Spritemap(atlas_handle));
}

fn spawn_camera(mut commands: Commands) {
    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle {
        projection: OrthographicProjection {
            scale: 1.00,
            ..default()
        },
        ..default()
    });
}

fn spawn_player(mut commands: Commands, sprites: Res<Spritemap>) {
    let mut sprite = TextureAtlasSprite::new(0);
    sprite.custom_size = Some(Vec2::splat(1.0));

    commands.spawn(SpriteSheetBundle {
        sprite,
        texture_atlas: sprites.0.clone(),
        transform: Transform {
            translation: Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            scale: Vec3::splat(100.0),
            ..default()
        },
        ..default()
    });//.insert(Name::new("Player"))

    commands.spawn(Player {
        name: "Pascal".to_string()
    });
}

#[derive(Component)]
pub struct Player {
    pub name: String,
}
```

My cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "bevy_simplerpg"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3

[dependencies]
bevy = "0.10.1"
```

This is the error message i get:

```
error[E0609]: no field `sampler` on type `&mut bevy::prelude::TextureAtlas`
  --> src\main.rs:37:29
   |
37 |                     texture.sampler = SamplerDescriptor {
   |                             ^^^^^^^ unknown field
   |
   = note: available fields are: `texture`, `size`, `textures`
```

I tried figuring out what [this](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/discussions/4305) entailed, and I got close, but I also kept getting errors using this method.

```
image.sampler_descriptor
```

Does not seem to have a

```
mag_filter
```

property. I don't know where else to access it.
I also don't know if this even works with TextureAtlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the [`texture`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/prelude/struct.TextureAtlas.html#structfield.texture) on the [`TextureAtlas`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/prelude/struct.TextureAtlas.html) and then set the [`sample_descriptor`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/render/texture/struct.Image.html#structfield.sampler_descriptor) of that [`Image`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/render/texture/struct.Image.html).

Based on your existing code one way this could be done is like so:

```rust
fn spritemap_fix(
    mut ev_asset: EventReader<AssetEvent<Image>>,
    mut assets: ResMut<Assets<Image>>,
) {
    for ev in ev_asset.iter() {
        match ev {
            AssetEvent::Created { handle } => {
                if let Some(texture) = assets.get_mut(&handle) {
                    texture.sampler_descriptor = ImageSampler::nearest()
                }
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

and then don't forget to add the system in your `main` function:

```rust
fn main() {
    App::new()
        //.add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
            primary_window: Option::from(Window {
                title: "Hi".to_string(),

                ..default()
            }),
            ..default()
        }))
        .insert_resource(ClearColor(BACKGROUND_COL))
        .add_startup_system(spawn_camera)
        .add_startup_system(load_spritemap)
        .add_startup_system(spawn_player.in_base_set(StartupSet::PostStartup))
        .add_system(spritemap_fix)
        .add_system(bevy::window::close_on_esc)
        .run();
}
```